# Numpy Row by Row Rotation

Tags: python, numpy, rotation

I have a 500x2 numpy array and a 2x2 rotation array.
I would like to rotate each row of the array using the rotation array.

I have tried

```
R.dot(A)
```

where R is the rotation array and A is the 500x2 array. But get the following error:

```
shapes (2,2) and (500,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 500 (dim 0)
```

Is there a way to do this row by row?

Thanks

Comment: ..`A.dot(R.T)` or `R.dot(A.T)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matrix multiplication, you need the inner dimensions to match (`m` by `n` and `n` by `k`). You're trying to multiply a 2 by 2 matrix with a 500 by 2 matrix - you need to take the transpose of the second matrix. Try

```
R.dot(A.transpose())
```

The columns of the result should be your rotated vectors. If you need it to be in row form, you can take the transpose again:

```
R.dot(A.transpose()).transpose()
```

Comment: I would like to do the multiplication row by row so it would be 2x2 (Rotation) and 2x1(each row) (nvm did not read full comment)